Getting 405 error when using the Tempo Datacentre api (note onpremise not cloud)
I'm expecting to get a list of Tempo worklogs for a specific project and within a specific range
I am trying to retrieve (and afterwards update) Tempo worklogs (data centre / server version). I am using basic authentication with the following URL http://jira.mycompany.co.uk/rest/tempo-timesheets/4/worklogs/search?projectKey=SPTKKR&from=2024-01-01&to=2024-10-14
The documentation I am following is from https://apidocs.tempo.io/dc/modules/timesheets.html?hsLang=en#tag/Worklogs/operation/searchWorklogs
Either I'm using the incorrect base URL or I'm going mad! The documentation says POST but I've tried GET as well just in case it was a misprint.
Has anybody got any insight to share?

Update : I had a little luck with a different api version. This time I managed to get a response except no matter what date range I inserted I could only get records that were logged today eg http://jira.mycompany.co.uk/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs?projectKey=SPTKKR&from=2024-01-01&to=2024-12-31
